# php &mysql and ajax(insert image into crud application)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

i need to add image field to here but i don't know way to  do it,i add few text field but i couldn't able to add image `

```
<div class="form-group">
   <label for="address">Thired step</label>
   <input type="text" id="address" placeholder="Thired step" class="form-control"/>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <!--<form method="POST" action="store_image.php" enctype="multipart/form-data"> -->
    <input type="file" name="imagee" id="imagee  class="form-control"/>
    <!--<input type="submit" name="submit_image" value="Upload"> -->

</div>

<div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="addRecord()" enctype="multipart/form-data">Add Help</button>
</div>`
```

this is addRecord.php`

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['first_name']))
    {
        // include Database connection file 
        include("db_connection.php");

        // get values 
        $first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
        $last_name = $_POST['last_name'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $address=$_POST['address'];
        $image=$_FILES['imagee']['name'];


        $query = "INSERT INTO users(first_name, last_name, email, address, image) VALUES('$first_name', '$last_name', '$email','$address','$image')";
        if (!$result = mysql_query($query)) {
            exit(mysql_error());
        }
        echo "1 Record Added!";
        $target="images/".basename($_FILES['imagee']['name']);
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['imagee']['tmp_name'],$target)){

        $msg="Image uploaded";
    }else{
        $msg="not uploaded";
    }
    }
?>`
```

this is script.js file`

```
// Add Record
function addRecord() {
    // get values
    var first_name = $("#first_name").val();
    var last_name = $("#last_name").val();
    var email = $("#email").val();
    var address=$("#address").val();
    var imagee  =$("#imagee").val();

    //$address=$_POST['address'];
    //$image=$_FILES['imagee']['name'];



    // Add record
    $.post("ajax/addRecord.php", {
        first_name: first_name,
        last_name: last_name,
        email: email,
        address:address,
        imagee:imagee
    }, function (data, status) {
        // close the popup
        $("#add_new_record_modal").modal("hide");

        // read records again
        readRecords();

        // clear fields from the popup
        $("#first_name").val("");
        $("#last_name").val("");
        $("#email").val("");
        $("#address").val("");
        $("#imagee").val("");

    });
}
```

i include all the file in my project please send me what are the changes i need to do add image and  complete this project.

`

Comment: this is my full code index.php

Comment: umm.. your `<form>` tag is commented.

Comment: can you please not use mysql* functions. It is no loner supported

Comment: You need to use form data to pass your image to your php script. Google search FormData.

Answer (score 0):

I really don't know what you are trying to accomplish here.  Also uncomment your form tag

```
<form method="POST" id="image_uploader" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Try this

```
var formData = new FormData($('#image_uploader')[0]); // This would dynamically grab all contents from your form including images and files.
```

Then, replace with,

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "ajax/addRecord.php",
        data: formData,
        //use contentType, processData for sure.
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        beforeSend: function() {
            //you can add a loading icon or loading message to tell your users something is happening
        },
        success: function(msg) {
            //hide modal on success and load
// close the popup
        $("#add_new_record_modal").modal("hide");

        // read records again
        readRecords();
        },
        error: function() {
           //show error message
        }
    });
```

Comment: actually i did this for text with out images it works can give me few tips how to add image

Comment: this is the same thing you do for images. The formdata takes care of that. This script will post the image as well to your server side(php). Make sure the destination directory where you save your images is writable and has required permissions. Do you get any error?

Comment: actually i did few this can u check and recode it to me

Comment: previously   i comment my hole inedx.php

Comment: var address=$("#address").val();
 var imagee  =$("#imagee").val();
 
 //$address=$_POST['address'];
 //$image=$_FILES['imagee']['name'];